# Ruby On rails, check if the checkbox is not empty

Tags: ruby-on-rails, checkbox

I have a checkbox and before I click on a submission button, I want to check if a checkbox is empty? if it is checked, a notification error should be shown.

```
<script src="/assets/rails.validations.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<%= form_for Groupsnorm.new, url: what_to_do_arraydbs_path ,method: :get ,:validate => true do |f| %>
  <div class="field_label">
    <%= f.label :group_name%>:
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%=f.text_field :group_name %>
  </div>

  <%= submit_tag "Submit", :commit =>"pictures" %> 
  <% @files.each do |file| %>                         
    <p><td> <%= check_box_tag "files[]", file.id %></td><%= arraydb.arraydb_file_name %></p>  
  <%end%>
<%end%>
```

and JavaScript looks something like this:

```
$(function validateCheckbox() {
  $('#notifications').ready(function() {
    $.notification( 
      {
        content: text,
        showTime: false,
        timeout: 5000,
        icon: "9",
      }
    );
  });
});
```

How is it possible to check if the checkbox is empty? Or is it possible to do a client side validation  so that "submit" button will not be clickable if checkbox is empty?

Answer (score 0):

in you controller write

```
if params[:CheckBoxNameAttribute]
{
// source code here
}
```

this checks whether your checkbox is checked or not